# Что значит "фиксировать имя" функции в php (NetBeans)?

Tags: php, netbeans

Пишу в NetBeans на php. Так вот IDE мне часто говорит, что надо фиксировать имя, например для такой функции

```
$str = strtoupper($exp);
```

Я соглашаюсь и тогда IDE добавляет `\` к имени функции

```
$str = \strtoupper($exp);
```

На работу кода это не влияет. Для чего это надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывается абсолютное имя fully qualified name. С глобального пространства имен.
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php

UPD: Информация отсюда http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.global.php

Без определения пространства имен, определения всех классов и функций находятся в глобальном пространстве - также как это было в PHP до введения пространств имен. Добавление префикса `\` к именам означает, что это имя должно находиться в глобальном пространстве, даже если вы находитесь в контексте определенного пространства имен.

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;

/* Эта функция является A\B\C\fopen */
function fopen() { 
     /* ... */
     $f = \fopen(...); // вызов глобальной функции fopen
     return $f;
} 
?>
```